# Add a checkbox with jquery into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to add a checkbox into a div into another div (with id="#sensorList"), and then bind some event handlers to it.
I do in this way

```
/* Add div */
$("#sensorList").append($('<div>', { id : sensorId})
.addClass("sensorListItem")
.text(sensorId)
);

/* Adds visibile checkbox */
$("#"+sensorId).append($('<input>', { id : sensorId + "VisibleCheckbox", type:"checkbox", name: sensorId + "VisibleCheckbox"}));
```

It seems to work fine, but if I click on checkbox, it doesn't switch to checked status!

Any idea?
Thank you in advance.

---

I'm so sorry, I figured out where the problem was.
I was unable to see the checkbox checked because I had a click handler on div called sensorId, and I stupidly did: event.preventDefault() (there is no default behaviour clicking on a div!!!)

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other code preventing the default action of the checbox, or that you simply placed another element on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

try some long hand and see if it works...

```
$("#"+sensorId).append('<input type="checkbox" id="' + sensorId + 'VisibleCheckbox" name="'  + sensorId + 'VisibleCheckbox" >');
```

Answer (score 2):

It works for me. Check out the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pVjNM/

```
var sensorId = "one";

/* Add div */
$("#sensorList").append($('<div>', { id : sensorId })
.addClass("sensorListItem")
.text(sensorId)
);

/* Adds visibile checkbox */
$("#"+sensorId).append($('<input>', { id : sensorId + "VisibleCheckbox", type:"checkbox", name: sensorId + "VisibleCheckbox"}));

$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    this.click();
    console.log("Should be true:", this.checked);
});


$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    this.click();
    console.log("Should be false:", this.checked);
});​
```